# How to simulate a periodic load pattern in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I want to repeatedly simulate load that gradually increases, reaches a peak and then gradually decreases. For example, I want to start with 10 HTTP requests for 1 minute, then 20....until 100 (assume this is the peak). Then when it reaches 100, I want the load gradually to fall, to 90,80,70 until it reaches 10.  What is the recommended way to achieve this?

Comment: You could design the scenario using [Stepping Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=SteppingThreadGroup)

Comment: @Adnan Thanks. Downloaded it and seems really nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the fastest and the easiest way of achieving this is using custom [Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) provided via JMeter Plugins project, i.e. [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/)

[image: Ultimate Thread Group]

The fastest and the easiest way of installing these Thread Groups and keeping them up-to-date is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager), after installing the Plugins Manager

1. Go to `Options -> Plugins Manager` from JMeter's main menu
2. Switch to `Available Plugins` tab
3. Locate `Custom Thread Groups` and tick the relevant box
4. Click `Apply Changes and Restart JMeter` button

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager]